# Can table insert duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a built a signup form  and the database is mysql.In the form when user enter username then it is verified through ajax request whether it exists or not.If it exists already then the new value is not accepted. Now suppose two user enters username at exactly the same time. While the query of first user run  it checks that username is available or not then at the same time query of user2 also runs. It will also search if username exists or not. Then can it be a possibility that mysql can enter same username for both the users as unless the username of first user is inserted into the table, search for user2 will give that username is available as both the query started at the same time. Is it so or i am making a mistake in understanding the concept. Please help ???

Comment: If there is no `UNIQUE` index/constraint or PRIMARY KEY on that column then yes. Share your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all depends on how you've setup your table.  If you've set your username column to be unique then no you cannot have a duplicate of the username regardless of how close together the queries execute, the second to hit will always fail.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

> The UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints both provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns.

Comment: you are right. But I think he executes validation when name is typed and then he submit the form. I think this validation has to be performed twice. Once on typing name and second on submitting form. Of course everythinkg has to be performed in transaction. Creating constraint solves this problem only partialy.

Comment: He was asking for an explanation of the concept, not how to perform username availability checking, but I agree you are correct this only solves one side of the issue -- the other side is code.